# dapper map one to one in classmapper

Tags: foreign-keys, dapper, relation, dapper-extensions

I have 2 simple tables.

```
create table Owner
(
    Id int primary key,
    Name nvarchar(100),
);

create table Status
(
    Id int primary key,
    BrandName nvarchar(50)
    OwnerId int foreign key references Owner(Id),
);
```

In app I map these tables to model classes:

```
public class Owner
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public Status Status {get;set;}
}


public class Status
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Brand {get;set;}
    public int OwnerId {get;set;}
}
```

I use dapper and dapper extension.

I would like map relation one to one in dapper in classmapper. It’s possible?

My goal is when I added owner object which has set up also property Status to db via repository 
it also insert record do status table.

What is best way to achieve this behavior?

```
public class OwnerMapper : ClassMapper<Owner>
{
    public OwnerMapper()
    {
        Table("Owner");
        Map(p=>p.Id).Column("Id").Key(KeyType.Assigned);
        Map(p=>p.Name).Column("Name");
        //how map property status

    }
}


public class StatusMapper : ClassMapper<Status>
{
    public StatusMapper()
    {
        Table("Status");
        Map(p=>p.Id).Column("Id").Key(KeyType.Identity);
        Map(p=>p.Brand).Column("BrandName");
        Map(p=>OwnerId).Column("OwnerId");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can try Dapper's [multi-mapping](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net#multi-mapping) feature:

```
[Test]
public void MyTest()
{
    var connection = new SqlConnection("conn string here");
    connection.Open();

    const string sql = 
        "select Id = 1, Name ='Bill Gates', Id = 1, Brand = 'Apple', OwnerId = 1";
    var result = connection.Query<Owner, Status, Owner>(sql,
                                           (owner, status) =>
                                               {
                                                   owner.Status = status;
                                                   return owner;
                                               },
                                           commandType: CommandType.Text
        ).FirstOrDefault();
    Assert.That(result, Is.Not.Null);
    Assert.That(result.Status, Is.Not.Null);
    Assert.That(result.Status.Brand, Is.EqualTo("Apple"));
    connection.Close();
}
```